# How to clear Editor log and Trace Log when using Automation Instrument

Tags: ios, testing, ios-ui-automation

I am using Automation Instrument to test out my iOS app. I was wondering how can I delete my old log messages from the Editor log and Trace Log?

The only way I know is to close my Profile window, open a new one and load in my JavaScript files in again. But there must be a simpler and smarter way to do this.

Comment: If you stop the recording on start it again (using the record button in the top left) then it should create a new Trace Log. The Editor log stays because it's supposed to provide a trace of everything that has happened. It's not ideal but the application itself is lacking a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately There is no simple or smarter way to do this yet. You need to restart the instruments IDE to clear the editor log. Alternatively you can wrap your code b/w logstart and logpass/logfail methods as below.

//Begin
UIALogger.logStart("Script start");

/* your test code
.......
*/

//End
UIALogger.logPass() or UIALogger.logFail() or UIALogger.logIssue()

With this you can make editor log grouped under a collapsable anchor and look less clumsy.